# Use variadic generics for method return specialization

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, typing, variadic

The goal is to have the following pseudocode valid in Python 3.7+ and have static analysis tools understand it.

```py
class VariadicType(MaybeASpecialBaseClass, metaclass=MaybeASpecialMetaClass):
    @classmethod
    def method(cls)->Union[???]:
        pass  # some irrelevant code

assert(VariadicType[Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4].method.__annotations__["return"] == Union[Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4])
assert(VariadicType[Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5].method.__annotations__["return"] == Union[Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5])
```

Is it possible to support some kind of `class VariadicType(Generic[...])` but then get all the passed generic types?

I was considering a C# approach of having

```py
class VariadicType(Generic[T1]):
...
class VariadicType(Generic[T1, T2]):
...
class VariadicType(Generic[T1, T2, T3]):
...
class VariadicType(Generic[T1, T2, T3, T4]):
...
class VariadicType(Generic[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]):
...
```

but that it not a valid code - `VariadicType` should only be defined once.

PS. the irrelevant part of code should be checking the `__annotations__["return"]` and returning results accordingly. It is applying mixins. If the return type is not a union of all applied mixins, then static analysis complains on missing fields and methods. Having a non-hinted code where types are given as method arguments but return type is `Any` is the last resort.

Comment: If you are building a static tool to check that, you want to do something similar as what the library ```mypy``` does. It reads the code and builds AST structures without executing it.

Comment: The goal is slightly more than that. Notice, that I’ve mentioned support for both static tools but the runtime as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already faced this problem, so maybe i can put some light on it.

### The problem

Suppose we have the next class definition:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
class VaradicType(Generic[T, S]):
    pass
```

The issue is that `VaradicType[T, S]` invokes `VaradicType.__class_getitem__((T, S))` which returns an object of the class  `_GenericAlias`.

Then, if you do `cls = VaradicType[int, float]`, you can introspect the arguments used as indices with
`cls.__args__`.

However, if you instantiate an object like `obj = cls()`, you cannot do `obj.__class__.__args__`. 
This is because `_GenericAlias` implements the method `__call__` that returns directly an object of `VaradicType` which dont have any class in its MRO that contains information about the arguments supplied.

```py
class VaradicType(Generic[T, S]):
    pass
cls = VaradicType[int, float]().__class__
print('__args__' in cls) # False
```

### One solution

One possible approach to solve this issue could be adding information about the generic arguments to the objects of the class `VaradicType` when they are instantiated.

First (following the previous code snippets), we will add a metaclass to `VaradicType`:

```py
class VaradicType(Generic[T, S], metaclass=GenericMixin):
    pass
```

We can use the fact that if `__getitem__` its defined on the metaclass, has priority over `__class_getitem__` in order to bypass `Generic.__class_getitem__`

```py
class GenericMixin(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, items):
        return GenericAliasWrapper(cls.__class_getitem__(items))
```

Now, `VaradicType[int, float]` is equivalent to `GenericMixin.__getitem__(VaradicType, (int, float))` and it will return an object of the class `GenericAliasWrapper` (it is used to "wrap" `typing._GenericAlias` instances):

```py
class GenericAliasWrapper:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.wrapped = x

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.wrapped.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.__dict__['__args__'] = self.wrapped.__args__
        return obj
```

Now, if you have `cls=VaradicType[int, float]`, the code `cls()` will be equivalent to 
 `GenericAliasWrapper( VaradicType.__class_getitem__((int, float)) ).__call__()` 
 which creates a new instance of the class `VaradicType` and also adds the attribute `__args__` to its dictionary.

e.g:

```py
VaradicType[int, float]().__args__ # (<class int>, <class float>)
```

Comment: Gave it a try. Didn't know about Metaclass `__getitem__`.